# Why do the breaks not work? The code still continues after they have been activated

Tags: python, loops, break

After the phone number is confirmed to be incorrect, and when the userTries and passTries is more than 2, the code still continues. Is there a way to stop this? I want the code to end where it says break. But it doesn’t. The code in the while True loop still runs after it.

```
import time

userTries = 0
passTries = 0

while True:
    # welcome user
    print('Welcome to [WEBSITE].')
    print('You must create an account to continue.')

    # variable inputs
    time.sleep(1)
    username = input('Please enter a username: ')
    password = input('Please enter a password: ')
    phonenum = int(input('Please enter your phone number for user confirmation: '))

    # account creation confirmation
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Welcome,', username + '.')
    print('Thank you for creating your account!')

    # re-enter username + password
    time.sleep(1)
    usernameQ = input('Please re-enter your username: ')

    while usernameQ != username:
        # username checker
        userTries += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        newusernameQ = input('Username incorrect, would you like to make a new username? (y or n) ')

        # (not) creating new username
        while newusernameQ not in ('Y', 'y', 'N', 'n'):
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Invalid answer.')
            newusernameQ = input('Would you like to make a new username? (y or n)')
        
        # phone number confirmation
        if newusernameQ in ('Y', 'y'):
            phonenumberQ = int(input('What is your phone number? '))
            
            if phonenumberQ != phonenum:
                time.sleep(1)
                print('Phone number incorrect. Account frozen.')
                break
            else:
                # re doing username
                time.sleep(1)
                username = input('Please enter a new username: ')
                time.sleep(1)
                print('Username set.')
                time.sleep(1)
                usernameQ = input('Please re-enter your username: ')
        else:
            # username ask
            usernameQ = input('Please re-enter your username: ')
        
        # tries too many
        if userTries > 2:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Too many attempts, account frozen.')
            break
    
    # asking for first password
    time.sleep(1)
    passwordQ = input('Please re-enter your password: ')

    # password checker
    while passwordQ != password:
        passTries += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        newpasswordQ = input('Password incorrect, would you like to make a new password? (y or n) ')

        # (not) creating new password
        while newpasswordQ not in ('Y', 'y', 'N', 'n'):
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Invalid answer.')
            newpasswordQ = input('Would you like to make a new password? (y or n)')
        
        # phone number confirmation
        if newpasswordQ in ('Y', 'y'):
            phonenumberQ = int(input('What is your phone number? '))
            
            if phonenumberQ != phonenum:
                time.sleep(1)
                print('Phone number incorrect. Account frozen.')
                break
            else:
                # re doing password
                time.sleep(1)
                password = input('Please enter a new password: ')
                time.sleep(1)
                print('Password set.')
                time.sleep(1)
                passwordQ = input('Please re-enter your password: ')
        else:
            # password ask
            passwordQ = input('Please re-enter your password: ')
        
        # tries too many
        if passTries > 2:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Too many attempts, account frozen.')
            break
    
    if passwordQ == password and usernameQ == username:
        for i in range(2):
            time.sleep(1)
            print('Logging in...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Login Successful.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Welcome, ' + username + '.')
        break
```

Comment: some of the code including the while true loop is included in the title annoyingly. Sorry about that, I don’t know how to fix it.

Comment: The `break` keyword only breaks out of the current `while` loop and not any others.

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the most recent loop. For instance you go 3 loops deep and hit `break` now the other 2 loops are still running. You need to write conditions that know you have performed a `break` and continue to `break` til you have exited every loop.

Comment: Simply put this code into a function and use `return` instead of `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand, that break only breaks out of your first while loop, not the main `while True` loop

Here is a simple example and mulitple choices for how to end the loop

The variable `something_other` is representing what ever other state you want to check to keep your while loop running.

**if running becomes False, the loops will run to the end and then print 'done'**

```
count = 0
running = True
something_other = True
while running:
    while something_other and running:
        print('start of while')
        count += 1
        if count > 2:
            running = False
        print('end of while')
    print('last line of outer loop')
print('done')
```

**Here running will become False and the inner loop will break and not print 'end of while' but the outer loop will run to the end and print 'last line of outer loop'**

```
count = 0
running = True
something_other = True
while running:
    while something_other and running:
        print('start of while')
        count += 1
        if count > 2:
            running = False
            break
        print('end of while')
    print('last line of outer loop')

print('done')
```

**And the last one will even break the outer loop as it checks for running after the inner loop is finished or exited with a break**

```
count = 0
running = True
something_other = True
while running:
    while something_other and running:
        print('start of while')
        count += 1
        if count > 2:
            running = False
            break
        print('end of while')
    if not running:
        break
    print('last line of outer loop')

print('done')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fully stop your program, consider using `sys.exit()`

Otherwise, a break statement only stops the most inner loop, the outer ones still continue. Thus, you need to add one break for each loop you want to stop.

Alternatively, you can define a boolean variable called "stop" and add it in your 'while' conditions. Something like:

```
while (usernameQ != username) and (not stop):
```

Comment: Are you certain you want to use ~stop ? If stop is assigned either True or False this will never be falsy. You would need to use -1 and some other value which isn't a typical approach in Python

Comment: Using the unary invert operator `~` is really strange here.